# Linker Errors while building a demo

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, directx-11

I recently purchased the "3D Game Programming with DirectX11" book. I wanted to try out the samples from the CD and for that I followed [this](http://d3dcoder.net/WordPress/) and many other support forum queries but for some reason its giving me following linker errors.

```
    1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Box, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1> fxc compile for debug: C:\Users\HashTable\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\D3DSamples\Chapter 6 Drawing in Direct3D\Box\FX\color.fx
1> Microsoft (R) Direct3D Shader Compiler 9.29.952.3111
1> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2002-2009. All rights reserved.
1>
1> compilation succeeded; see color.cod
1> compilation succeeded; see C:\Users\HashTable\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\D3DSamples\Chapter 6 Drawing in Direct3D\Box\FX\color.fxo
1> BoxDemo.cpp
1> MathHelper.cpp
1> GeometryGenerator.cpp
1> GameTimer.cpp
1> d3dUtil.cpp
1> d3dApp.cpp
1> Generating Code...
1>Effects11d.lib(EffectAPI.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1600' doesn't match value '1700' in d3dApp.obj
1>Effects11d.lib(EffectNonRuntime.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1600' doesn't match value '1700' in d3dApp.obj
1>Effects11d.lib(EffectLoad.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1600' doesn't match value '1700' in d3dApp.obj
1>Effects11d.lib(EffectReflection.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1600' doesn't match value '1700' in d3dApp.obj
1>Effects11d.lib(d3dx11dbg.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1600' doesn't match value '1700' in d3dApp.obj
1>Effects11d.lib(d3dxGlobal.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1600' doesn't match value '1700' in d3dApp.obj
1>Effects11d.lib(EffectRuntime.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1600' doesn't match value '1700' in d3dApp.obj
1>C:\Users\HashTable\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\D3DSamples\Chapter 6 Drawing in Direct3D\Box\Debug\Box.exe : fatal error LNK1319: 7 mismatches detected
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have tried building Rel and Debug builds in VS 2012 for Effects library from the code obtained from MSDN codeplex and DirectX SDK 2010. I have moved them to the specified location but still these errors show up. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**D3DX Library [is deprecated](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx).**

But I think there's a copy included on the book CD so try to link it from there. Look in the Common folder if I remember correctly.

*Still, it's deprecated...*

Comment: Author advises to build the Effects lib from the scratch.That's why I have been trying to build them. But the default ones from the CD/online codebase are also not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still seeing those errors after rebuilding the effects libraries, you probably have different platforms targeted. Make sure that the Platform Toolset is the same in both projects:

[image: prop]

Comment: Platform toolset are same for both libs and the project. Its still not working. :(

Comment: @Recker Then perhaps you need to check Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories, and VC++ Directories->Libraries to make sure the libs you just built are the ones being imported.